# Fiddler and capturing traffic that is coming through ICS

Tags: proxy, fiddler, portforwarding

**Core Problem:**

How do I get Fiddler to capture traffic coming through a network adapter that is using ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) to access the Internet.

**Background**:

OS Windows 8.1 Update 1 x64

I have a computer with 2 NICs. NIC1 is connected to my router and has internet access. NIC2 is connected to another WiFi router that additional devices will connect to such as smart devices that are not proxy aware. The device router is a Linux based router.

NIC1 is using ICS to share internet access to NIC2.

I can see the information coming in via WireShark and the devices themselves are connecting to the internet over ICS.

Fiddler does not seem to be picking up the traffic that is coming via NIC2.

Fiddler is capturing requests from my browser to the web server UI that is running on the router that is connected to NIC2 and any traffic that originates on my PC outgoing.

**What I have tried**

I have tried using the command **NETSH winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:8888** to set the global winhttp proxy to route through Fiddler but that doesn't seem to work

I also tried port forwarding on the the windows side using **NETSH interface portproxy** and listening on the ip address of NIC2 and port 80 and forwarding to the NIC1 IP and port 8888 and this didnt work.

I have tried doing some port forwarding on the device router to do port forwarding with iptables but to be honest, I don't fully understand how this works.

The commands I have ran

**iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8888**

Any ideas & comments are appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Fiddler isn't a packet capture tool; it shows the traffic that is sent to it, rather than traffic that just happens to be flowing through the PC.

The client devices should be configured to proxy their traffic to the IP address of the Fiddler-running PC, at port 8888.

Setting WinHTTP's proxy on the Fiddler-running machine won't help, and generally trying to use port-forwarding to make Fiddler act like a transparent proxy will not be reliable.

If you only need to *see* traffic but don't need to *modify* it, simply grab a PCAP of the traffic and import it using Fiddler's File > Import command.

Comment: The client devices cannot be configured that way, which is the crux of the problem and it is why I am trying to do a IP forward on it but failing

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

Some android browser seems not sending request through android system proxy. My miuibrowser just ignores the system proxy.

Fiddler seems can capture the 8888 port traffic if "Allow remote computer to connect" is on.

After searching on google, one working way is to foward the router's port 80 traffic to my pc's 8888 port, so that fiddler can capture. And the phone can connect to router's wifi without any proxy settings.

Below is the command:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.137.1:8888
```

I am using tomato dual-wan router and the command is a little different.